# Get names of open notebooks

Tags: notebooks

I would like to be able to delete any open notebook with some specific text string in its name. Notebooks[] returns a list of open notebook objects, but to get the names, I am using a kluge involving

```
ToString[NotebookGet[#]]&/@Notebooks[]
```

followed by using StringPosition[#,"WindowsTitle"] and then StringTake[] based on the string positions returned. When I get the exact name of the notebook of interest, it's easy to close it with NotebookClose[name].

I'll bet there is a very straightforward way to extract properties from notebook objects.  But I can't find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the open notebooks have already a filename (ie if they have been saved somewhere) :

```
NotebookFileName /@ Notebooks[]
```

otherwise you can use :

```
NotebookInformation /@ Notebooks[]
```

Comment: It's so simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Does:

```
AbsoluteCurrentValue[Notebooks[], WindowTitle]
```

work for you?

Comment: I knew there was an easy way. Thanks!

Comment: @Carl Woll: Is there a way like your suggestion above to list the names of all the variables and tagged cells in a notebook?